# Why can't the Minecraft Launcher connect to its servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, networking, minecraft-launcher

I'm playing the demo version on a Mac and every time I log in, it says *Sorry, but we can't connect to our servers. Please make sure that you are online and that Minecraft isn't blocked.* [image: Every time I try, this always happens. It's been like this for days.]

Comment: Have you made sure your Firewall is either off or making an exception for Java?

Answer (score 0):

First, attempt to uninstall Java and reinstall it. If you are using a 32 Bit machine, refrain from getting the 64 Bit Version. People mess that up a lot

If that doesn't work, delete the entire .minecraft folder. Back up any saves/mods/resourcepacks you want to keep. redownload the launcher

Also save the servers.dat file in case you want to keep your servers that you don't remember the IP :)

Third, check your internet connection. If you are using WiFi, make sure you are reasonable distance from your router.

Make sure there isn't anything wrong with the Minecraft.net website. Try logging in there or at Mojang.com. Try migrating your account.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking https://help.mojang.com/.

If all the servers are up on the page try going to http://login.minecraft.net

I think that will work.

Comment: You should place this into the comment section. Because you are unsure of this information and this will not get approved as the "right" answer.